# Why does Python give the "wrong" answer for square root? What is integer division in Python 2?

Tags: python, math, python-2.x, sqrt

```
x = 16

sqrt = x**(.5)  #returns 4
sqrt = x**(1/2) #returns 1
```

I know I can `import math` and use `sqrt`, but I'm looking for an answer to the above. What is integer division in Python 2? This behavior is fixed in Python 3.

Comment: Try it in Python 3, it's fixed ;)

Comment: [Canonical version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70793490/17242583).

Answer (score 278, accepted):

In Python 2, `sqrt=x**(1/2)` does integer division. `1/2 == 0`.

So x<sup>(1/2)</sup> equals x<sup>(0)</sup>, which is 1.

It's not wrong, it's the right answer to a different question.

If you want to calculate the square root without an import of the math module, you'll need to use `x**(1.0/2)` or `x**(1/2.)`.  One of the integers needs to be a floating number.

Note: this is not the case in Python 3, where `1/2` would be `0.5` and `1//2` would instead be integer division.

Comment: in Python 3.6 you get the right answer to the question you first asked.

Comment: The second method can be computed as: `sqrt = x**(float(1)/2)`

Answer (score 133):

You have to write: `sqrt = x**(1/2.0)`, otherwise an integer division is performed and the expression `1/2` returns `0`.

This behavior is "normal" in Python 2.x, whereas in Python 3.x `1/2` evaluates to `0.5`. If you want your Python 2.x code to behave like 3.x w.r.t. division write `from __future__ import division` - then `1/2` will evaluate to `0.5` and for backwards compatibility, `1//2` will evaluate to `0`.

And for the record, the preferred way to calculate a square root is this:

```
import math
math.sqrt(x)
```

Answer (score 14):

`/` performs an integer division in Python 2:

```
>>> 1/2
0
```

If one of the numbers is a float, it works as expected:

```
>>> 1.0/2
0.5
>>> 16**(1.0/2)
4.0
```

Answer (score 7):

What you're seeing is integer division. To get floating point division by default,

```
from __future__ import division
```

Or, you could convert 1 or 2 of 1/2 into a floating point value.

```
sqrt = x**(1.0/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple way to remember: add a dot after the numerator (or denominator)

```
16 ** (1. / 2)   # 4
289 ** (1. / 2)  # 17
27 ** (1. / 3)   # 3
```