# How to find the cube root in Python?

Tags: python

I've tried to find the cube root in Python but I have no idea how to find it. There was 1 line of code that worked but he wouldn't give me the full number. Example:

```
math.pow(64, 1/3)
```

This doesn't give me 4 tough but 3.99999. Does anyone know how I am supposed to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is cube root integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621833/is-cube-root-integer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a short-hand for nth root of x in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255120/is-there-a-short-hand-for-nth-root-of-x-in-python)

Comment: `round(math.pow(64,1/3))` is a quick fix

Answer (score 14):

You can use the power operator `**` with fractions like:

Python3:

```
>>> 8**(1/3)
2.0
```

Python2:

```
>>> 8**(1.0/3)
2.0
```

Answer (score 11):

in `Python 3.11`, `math.cbrt`

```
 x = 64
 math.cbrt(x)
```

(or)

use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
x = 64
np.cbrt(x)
```

Comment: `np.cbrt` handles also negative numbers properly. Maybe `math.cbrt` does too, I do not know about that bit.

Answer (score 8):

This is one option without using math library

```
>>> 64**(1/3)
3.9999999999999996
>>> round(64**(1/3.),2)
4.0
```

If you want to do with your code, you can apply 'round()' method

```
>>>import math
>>>round(math.pow(64,1/3.))
4
```