# How to get a cube root in Python

Tags: python

I saw this post recently, about getting square roots in python: [How to calc square root in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9595135/6759115)

I have used the `sqrt(x)` command, but I don't know how to make it work for cube roots and anything higher than that.

Also, I'm using Python 3.5.2.

Any help on this?

Comment: @Karin Thanks, I didn't see that post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, you may find floating `cube root` by:

```
>>> def get_cube_root(num):
...     return num ** (1. / 3)
... 
>>> get_cube_root(27)
3.0
```

In case you want more generic approach to find `nth root`, you may use below code which is based on `Newton's method`:

```
# NOTE: You may use this function only for integer numbers
# k is num, n is the 'n' in nth root
def iroot(k, n):
    u, s = n, n+1
    while u < s:
        s = u
        t = (k-1) * s + n // pow(s, k-1)
        u = t // k
    return s
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see in what cases your `iroot` is better than `k ** (1./n)`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Indeed... And the function as provided returns wrong results (in both 2.7 and 3.5, using `//` or `/` division).