# Keyerror : Creating a dataframe column using square root of the sum of square of two column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column A and B. I want to create a third column which is square root of the sum of squares of two columns.

Below is my sample data:

```
A   B
10  7
10  8
9   8
10  11
13  5
3   0
12  8
12  9
11  10
10  11
```

Below is the code that I have tried:

```
df['vib_mot_sqrt'] = df[(np.sqrt(df['X']**2) + (df['index']**2))]
```

> KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([6.0, 6.0, 11.0, 15.0, 16.0, 33.0, 42.0, 55.0, 73.0, 87.0], dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Sum of square root? Where are you doing that? I just see one `sqrt`

Comment: yes, both would you've said and your code contradict themselves

Comment: Your question title and the code implementation are confusing. Please explain what do you want people to solve

Comment: @ Sheldore thanks for point out. It was a typing error. I have edited the title and summary part of my question. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please clarify do you want to calculate exactly one value or value for each row?

If you want to calculate value for each row and add it to the new column this should do it:

```
df['C']= np.sqrt(df['A']**2+df['B']**2)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0   4   5   6.403124
1   3   3   4.242641
2   1   1   1.414214
```

Comment: I wanted to calculate the value for each row. You have rightly answered my query. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I get a “runtimewarning: invaid value encountered in sqrt.” Any tips for solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [square root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9595150) with both columns and sum:

```
df['vib_mot_sqrt'] = df['A']**.5 + df['B']**.5
print (df)
    A   B  vib_mot_sqrt
0  10   7      5.808029
1  10   8      5.990705
2   9   8      5.828427
3  10  11      6.478902
4  13   5      5.841619
5   3   0      1.732051
6  12   8      6.292529
7  12   9      6.464102
8  11  10      6.478902
9  10  11      6.478902
```

My original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56130307/revisions):

```
df['vib_mot_sqrt'] = np.sqrt(df['A']**2 + (df['B']**2))
print (df)
    A   B  vib_mot_sqrt
0  10   7     12.206556
1  10   8     12.806248
2   9   8     12.041595
3  10  11     14.866069
4  13   5     13.928388
5   3   0      3.000000
6  12   8     14.422205
7  12   9     15.000000
8  11  10     14.866069
9  10  11     14.866069
```

Comment: @Sheldore - Thank you, answer was changed.

Comment: @ jezrael, Great ! thanks for the input. I was using df over the np.sqrt earlier. There was no need for that. Now it's absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.sqrt(x)` for square root and `x**a` for the power:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
                   [10 , 7],
                   [10 , 8],
                   [9  , 8],
                   [10 , 11],
                   [13 , 5],
                   [3  , 0],
                   [12 , 8],
                   [12 , 9],
                   [11 , 10],
                   [10 ,11],],
                  columns=["A"  , "B"])

df["sqrt(A²+B²)"] = np.sqrt(df["A"]**2 + df["B"]**2)

print(df)
#     A   B  sqrt(A²+B²)
# 0  10   7    12.206556
# 1  10   8    12.806248
# 2   9   8    12.041595
# 3  10  11    14.866069
# 4  13   5    13.928388
# 5   3   0     3.000000
# 6  12   8    14.422205
# 7  12   9    15.000000
# 8  11  10    14.866069
# 9  10  11    14.866069
```